# What is the probability of having two hearts in a randomly drawn hand of 5 cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm currently doing a probability unit, and one of the formulas I have learned is:

$$n_{C_{x}} (P^{x}) (1-p)^{n-x}$$

So for example:

James is practicing penalties. His chance of scoring with each shot is 0.7. He currently takes 40 shots.

What is the probability he scores 32 times?
Answer: 
$$\binom{40}{32} \cdot \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^{32} \cdot \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{8} = 0.0557$$

Now, back to the original question. "What is the probability of having two hearts in a randomly drawn hand of 5 cards?"

I tried using the formula and came up with this equation:

$$ \binom{5}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{13}{52}\right)^{2} \cdot \left(\frac{39}{52}\right)^{3} = 0.2637 $$
The correct answer to this question is 0.2743.

For another slightly different question, the same thing happens.

What is the probability of a 5-card hand containing three hearts?

$$ \binom{5}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{13}{52}\right)^{3} \cdot \left(\frac{39}{52}\right)^{2} = 0.0879 $$
The correct answer is 0.0815.

As you can see, each time I get pretty close to the correct answer, but not the exact answer. My question is, can this equation be modified/fixed in order to get the correct answers to the two questions above?

Comment: What is the probability of a 5-card hand containing three aces of hearts? Is it $$\binom53\cdot\left(\frac1{52}\right)^3\cdot\left(\frac{51}{52}\right)^2=0.0000684?$$

Comment: @bof Is the question correct? Each 52-card deck only has 1 ace of hearts, so you can't get 3 aces of hearts in one hand.

Comment: @user467522 That is bof's point.  The formula says the probability for an impossible event is not zero --- so therefore, the formula is inapplicable.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oh I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probabilities in a card hand can't be accurately calculated using the binomial formula. The binomial formula models a Bernoulli experiment, i.e., one where the probability of "success" doesn't change from trial to trial. There are only $52$ cards in a deck, and as soon as one is dealt, the probabilities for what happens with the second card are different, because it's being dealt from a different, $51$-card deck now. Your answers were close to correct, because the probabilities don't change by very much.

If you want to know the probability of getting two hearts in a $5$-card hand, just count up how many such hands there are, and put that number over the total number of possible $5$-card hands:

$$\frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{39}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

The first binomial coefficient counts the number of ways of choosing two hearts, the second counts the number of ways of choosing three non-hearts, and the denominator counts the number of possible hands.